# gRPC not working after dockerizing microservice in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker-compose, microservices, grpc

I have a microservice application running in .NET 8 and Docker, the Auction and Bid service are supposed to communicate via gRPC. It worked completely fine until I moved the Bid service to Docker like the rest, but now I get the same exception every time. The Auction (auction-svc is the gRPC server and the bid-svc is the client). I am using the Grpc.AspNetCore nuget package in Auction, Grpc.Net.Client / Grpc.Tools / Google.Protobuf in the Bid service.

All of the configurations, as I'm following a guide, worked in the example and the HTTP/2 should be handled correctly. What am I missing to get this to work on Docker (for Windows).

Docker compose

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgrespw"
      POSTGRES_DB: "Auctions"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
  #      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpw"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mongo
  #      - mongodata:/var/lib/mongo

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/rabbitmq
  auction-svc:
    image: amg31/auction-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/AuctionService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7777
      - RabbitMq__Host=rabbitmq
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres:5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=postgrespw;Database=Auctions
      - IdentityServiceUrl=http://identity-svc
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Protocols=Http2
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Url=http://+:7777
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__WebApi__Protocols=Http1
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__WebApi__Url=Http://+:80
    ports:
      - 7001:80
      - 7777:7777
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
  search-svc:
    image: amg31/search-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/SearchService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - RabbitMq__Host=rabbitmq
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=mongodb://root:rootpw@mongo:27017
      - AuctionServiceUrl=http://auction-svc
    ports:
      - 7002:80
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
  identity-svc:
    image: amg31/identity-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/IdentityService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=postgres:5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=postgrespw;Database=Identity
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  gateway-svc:
    image: amg31/gateway-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/GatewayService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    ports:
      - 6001:80
  bid-svc:
    image: amg31/bid-svc:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/BiddingService/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - RabbitMq__Host=rabbitmq
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=mongodb://root:rootpw@mongo:27017
      - IdentityServiceUrl=http://identity-svc
      - GrpcAuction=http://auction-svc:7777
    ports:
      - 7003:80
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq



#      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
#volumes:
#  postgresdata:
#  mongodata:
#  rabbitmq:
```

Auction Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 7777

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers. Use of the same COPY command to copy the csproj file and the 
# rest of the files is a best practice to take advantage of Docker's layer caching. This way, Docker can 
# reuse the layers created during the restore operation if the csproj file has not changed.
COPY AuctionNext.sln AuctionNext.sln
COPY src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj
COPY src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj
COPY src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj
COPY src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj
COPY src/BiddingService/BiddingService.csproj src/BiddingService/BiddingService.csproj
COPY src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj
COPY tests/AuctionService.UnitTests/AuctionService.UnitTests.csproj tests/AuctionService.UnitTests/AuctionService.UnitTests.csproj
COPY tests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests.csproj tests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests.csproj
COPY tests/SearchService.UnitTests/SearchService.UnitTests.csproj tests/SearchService.UnitTests/SearchService.UnitTests.csproj

# Restore the dependencies
RUN dotnet restore AuctionNext.sln

# Copy the app folders
COPY src/AuctionService src/AuctionService
COPY src/Contracts src/Contracts

# publish the app
WORKDIR /app/src/AuctionService
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/src/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuctionService.dll"]
```

Bidding service Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers. Use of the same COPY command to copy the csproj file and the 
# rest of the files is a best practice to take advantage of Docker's layer caching. This way, Docker can 
# reuse the layers created during the restore operation if the csproj file has not changed.
COPY AuctionNext.sln AuctionNext.sln
COPY src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj src/AuctionService/AuctionService.csproj
COPY src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj src/SearchService/SearchService.csproj
COPY src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj src/IdentityService/IdentityService.csproj
COPY src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj src/GatewayService/GatewayService.csproj
COPY src/BiddingService/BiddingService.csproj src/BiddingService/BiddingService.csproj
COPY src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj
COPY tests/AuctionService.UnitTests/AuctionService.UnitTests.csproj tests/AuctionService.UnitTests/AuctionService.UnitTests.csproj
COPY tests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests.csproj tests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests/AuctionService.IntegrationTests.csproj
COPY tests/SearchService.UnitTests/SearchService.UnitTests.csproj tests/SearchService.UnitTests/SearchService.UnitTests.csproj

# Restore the dependencies
RUN dotnet restore AuctionNext.sln

# Copy the app folders
COPY src/BiddingService src/BiddingService
COPY src/Contracts src/Contracts

# publish the app
WORKDIR /app/src/BiddingService
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/src/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/src/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BiddingService.dll"]
```

Appsettings for Auction

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Grpc": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost:5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=postgrespw;Database=Auctions"
  },
  "IdentityServiceUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "RabbitMq": {
    "Host": "localhost"
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Grpc": {
        "Protocols": "Http2",
        "Url": "http://localhost:7777"
      },
      "WebApi": {
        "Protocols": "Http1",
        "Url": "http://localhost:7001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Appsettings for Bidding Service

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Grpc": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "mongodb://root:rootpw@localhost:27017"
  },
  "IdentityServiceUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
  "RabbitMq": {
    "Host": "localhost"
  },
  "GrpcAuction": "http://localhost:7777"
}
```

auctions.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "AuctionService";

service GrpcAuction {
  rpc GetAuction (GetAuctionRequest) returns (GrpcAuctionResponse);
}

message GetAuctionRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message GrpcAuctionModel {
  string id = 1;
  string seller = 2;
  string auctionEnd = 3;
  int32 reservePrice = 4;
}

message GrpcAuctionResponse {
  GrpcAuctionModel auction = 1;
}
```

class where the stuff gets called:

```
public class GrpcAuctionClient
{
    private readonly ILogger<GrpcAuctionClient> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public GrpcAuctionClient(ILogger<GrpcAuctionClient> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }

    public Auction GetAuction(string id)
    {

        _logger.LogInformation("Calling GRPC Service");
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(_config["GrpcAuction"]);
        var client = new GrpcAuction.GrpcAuctionClient(channel);
        var request = new GetAuctionRequest {Id = id};

        try
        {
            var reply = client.GetAuction(request);
            var auction = new Auction
            {
                ID = reply.Auction.Id,
                AuctionEnd = DateTime.Parse(reply.Auction.AuctionEnd),
                Seller = reply.Auction.Seller,
                ReservePrice = reply.Auction.ReservePrice
            };

            return auction;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Could not call GRPC Server");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding this line in several place, didn't help

```
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
```

And FINALLY, the exception that's thrown each time now that it's in docker.

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Exception was thrown by handler.")
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at AuctionService.GrpcAuction.GrpcAuctionClient.GetAuction(GetAuctionRequest request, CallOptions options) in /app/src/BiddingService/obj/Release/net8.0/protos/AuctionsGrpc.cs:line 102
   at AuctionService.GrpcAuction.GrpcAuctionClient.GetAuction(GetAuctionRequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /app/src/BiddingService/obj/Release/net8.0/protos/AuctionsGrpc.cs:line 97
   at BiddingService.Services.GrpcAuctionClient.GetAuction(String id) in /app/src/BiddingService/Services/GrpcAuctionClient.cs:line 29
   at BiddingService.Controllers.BidsController.PlaceBid(String auctionId, Int32 amount) in /app/src/BiddingService/Controllers/BidsController.cs:line 36
   at lambda_method9(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Not much of a .NET developer. Using Docker (Compose) should **not** affect gRPC particularly IIUC you ran everything except `bid-svc` using Docker Compose beforehand and `bid-svc` worked when running externally. Are you confident you've correctly mapped the config correctly? E.g. `GrpcAuction=http://auction-svc:7777` does .NET mandate the use of `http://` when using gRPC? `bid-svc` does not `depends_on` `auction-svc`. You have various `ports` mappings `{host-port}:{container-port}`, the `{host-port}` values will not be relevant to `bid-svc` once under docker-compose.

Comment: You're answer is comprehensive but it is not a minimal repro. If you struggle to get answers here, consider providing a simpler repro of the issue.

Comment: I was actually ALSO running the auction-svc locally and NOT via docker at the time. Since it was the gRPC server, I had both of those running locally first while I tested that but before implementing gRPC it was running via docker just fine.